# How to enqueue javascript in my theme in wordpress that i created?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, templates, enqueue

I converted a html,css,js template to a wordpress theme.
To enqueue my css it worked correctly, i just add the function in functions.php but to enqueue javascript it doesn't work i tryed a lot of modifications but nothing works
Here is my function.php

```js
<?php


function load_stylesheets()
{
 
 wp_register_style('normal',get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css',  array(), 1, 'all');
 wp_enqueue_style('normal');
 
 
 
 wp_register_style('demonstration',get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/demo.css',  array(), 1, 'all');
 wp_enqueue_style('demonstration');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_stylesheets');





function addjs()
{
  
 
 wp_register_script('anime', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/anime.min.js', array(), 1,1, 1);
 wp_enqueue_script('anime');
 
 
 wp_register_script('imagesload', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', array(), 1,1, 1);
 wp_enqueue_script('imagesload');
 
 
 wp_register_script('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array(), 1,1, 1);
 wp_enqueue_script('main');
 

  
}
```

Comment: You need to `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addjs');` too

Comment: I already do it but it changed nothing, and in many cases i saw in other posts that they don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this

```
add_action('wp_footer','addjs');

function addjs() {

    wp_register_script('anime', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/anime.min.js', array ('jquery'),'',true);

    wp_register_script('imagesload', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', array ('jquery'),'',true);


    wp_register_script('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array ('jquery'),'',true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short-and-sweet of it is that you're not calling your `addjs` function anywhere. If you added:

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addjs' );`

Then it should work. (*Note: anyone that the above doesn't work for, look at the **edit** below*)

However, there's a couple things you should note:

- Make sure your indenting/spacing is consistent, and you don't have extraneous whitespace after lines. Clean code is key!
- You don't need to add JS and CSS files separately, they can both be handled in the same `add_action` function callback.
- Unless you're doing some really fancy stuff (enqueueing only while a shortcode is found on a page, etc.), `wp_enqueue_{script/style}` will take care of the `wp_register_{script/style}` function for you. In most cases you can use `enqueue` them instead of *registering* and then *enqueueing* them.
- Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and make sure your arguments are the same as the ones the function accepts. It will prevent warnings and errors in more extreme cases.

Here's a cleaned up example for you:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_theme_assets' );
function enqueue_theme_assets(){
    // Styles
    wp_enqueue_style( 'normal', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css', array(), '1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'demonstration', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/demo.css', array(), '1.0');

    // Scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'anime', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/anime.min.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'imagesload', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', array(),'1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array(), '1.0', true );
}
```

---

## EDIT:

I just saw your comment that `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addjs' );` wasn't working. Take a look at the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) docs. You'll note in the [#Usage](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#usage) section, that it properly enqueuing scripts on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook relies on the [`wp_footer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/) and [`wp_head()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) functions being utilized in your theme, so **make sure you have `wp_footer();` called in your theme, especially since you have the `$in_footer` argument set to `true`.

Comment: Thank u for the organized code, i will try this and take a look to this documentation.

Answer (score 0):

wp_enqueue_scripts is the proper hook to use when enqueuing scripts and styles that are meant to appear on the front end. Despite the name, it is used for enqueuing both scripts and styles.

So You have to add scripts and styles inside one function or you can add one more wordpress action with your existing code.

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addjs' );`